# async.parallel() - last function not being called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

For some reason the 'yyyyyyyyy' string is never printed when I use async.parallel() as per below. Why is this? I thought that the last function would be called once the other two have been called.

```
var async = require('async');
async.parallel([
    function() {
        console.log('xxxxxxxxxxx');
    },
    function() {
        console.log('ccccccccccc');
    }
], function(err, results){
    console.log('yyyyyyyyy');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every `function` passed in the first parameter to `async.parallel` should take a `callback` that it calls when its done so `async` knows that it has completed:

```
var async = require('async');
async.parallel([
    function(callback) {
        console.log('xxxxxxxxxxx');
        callback();
    },
    function(callback) {
        console.log('ccccccccccc');
        callback();
    }
], function(err, results){
    console.log('yyyyyyyyy');
});
```

If an error happens in one of the `functions`, it should call the `callback` with

```
callback(err);
```

so that `async` knows an error has occurred and it'll immediately call the last `function`.